# Submit Textarea 403 Error

Tags: text, yii2, submit, php-7, http-status-code-403

Im having this problem on my live server only. 
It is running Linux and PHP 7.0
I think perhaps this problem has to do with security settings on the server but i cant be sure?
i am using PHP 7 and Yii 2 Framework
When i submit this exact text in a textarea i get a 403 error:

Conditions:
Copy of

I have narrowed it down to the above piece of text.
Just copying and pasting in that exact piece of text results in 403 error

I have found that disabling Mod_Security fixes the issue.
It seems to be a false positive trigerring mod_security?

Comment: Can you share corresponding action/model/view code? Otherwise is just guessing.

Comment: I can share the code - but it doesnt even have a chance to run.
When submitting the form it goes straight to 403 error.

Comment: When i disable MOD_SECURITY it fixes the problem

Comment: Maybe mod_security think its a header injection attack type (since the posted text has an header-like format) and block it.

Comment: is this happening when you enter any of these characters too `(like % or $ or ' or #)`.